# The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i use Callback in google map api key then i am getting error.

Here is my code

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initializ&key=' + '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleMapApiKey"].ToString()';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: sounds like you've got the wrong key.  Does the generated javascript output look like it has a valid value for the key attribute?

Comment: PS: you don't need to pass the `&sensor=false` attribute any more.

Comment: are you using the iOS key instead of the server/browser key? I do not think the iOS key works for javascript even it is in the webview.